# Do you know how to set about solr not present _"str"?

Tags: solr

I used Apache Solr to indexing database, the problem is created field named "*_str". someone told update.autoCreateFields:true change false. But it still works!. please help me and my memory :(

In java, for example, I used SolrInputDocument.addField("A", valueOfA), SolrInputDocument.addField("B", valueOfB). 
Then, Solr present 
"A" : "vauleofA"
"B" : "vauleofB"
"A_str" : "vauleofA"
"B_str" : "vauleofB"

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what’s your issue is? It’s unclear right now

Answer (score 2):

In a standard Solr 7 installation when Solr automatically adds a field (e.g. when `update.autoCreateFields` is set to `true`) you will get these `_str` fields also added by default. For example if you add the following document to Solr:

```
[
  { "id": "test01", "somefield": "hello world" }
]
```

You will see two fields in your schema `somefield` and `somefield_str`. I believe the configuration for the additional `_str` field is defined in the `solrconfig.xml` file under (look for `AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory`) -- but I am not sure about this.

If you set `autoCreateFields` to `false` after you have imported the document that created those fields, those fields *will remain in your schema* (and on the documents that already have them.) You will need to recreate your schema in order to get rid of them.